# Creating data in SQLite database manually in Vapor

Tags: swift, sqlite, vapor, server-side-swift

How to add data to SQLite database manually in Vapor project so that at startup there's already some data in it?

Comment: What do you mean exactly because it sounds that you have already answered your own question, you add data manually by adding it manually. I know that wasn't what  you meant so please clarify.

Comment: I mean adding objects programmatically to the database, I didn't find solution how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this:

```
struct CreateAdminUser: Migration {

    static func prepare(on connection: SQLiteConnection) -> Future<Void> {
        let password = try? BCrypt.hash("secret")
        let user = User(email: "me@example.co.uk", password: password!)
        return user.save(on: connection).transform(to: ())
    }

    static func revert(on connection: SQLiteConnection) -> Future<Void> {
        return Future.map(on: connection) {}
    }
}
```

I then put this line into `configure.swift` migrations:

```
migrations.add(migration: CreateAdminUser.self, database: .sqlite)
```